# Continuous Integration monitoring inside an intranet

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, agile, weblogic, clearcase

I'm thinking about extending our continuous integration framework at work and wanted to know how easy the following would be. Also any pointers as to where to start.

We use an Ant build to build an Oracle Service Bus project and SOAPUI to run automated tests. I want to move over to using Hudson instead of Continuum for continuous integration. I also want better real time monitoring. For example connecting Hudson up to a Twitter like service that can be easily shown on a friendly dashboard for the project.

My only issue is that our network doesn't have a connection to the internet so I can't reuse already built Twitter plugins. Is there a way to set up a (preferably free) Twitter like service on our intranet that can be hooked into Hudson? Has anyone had any experience of this?

Comment: You might consider StatusNet (formerly Laconica) as your twitter alternative. My recollection is that the API is pretty similar.  Also, you should probably use Jenkins instead of Hudson. It's the new name for Hudson, and all the core Hudson developers moved over.

Comment: Is there any reason it has to be Twitter (or similar)? Hudson/Jenkins has a range of notification plugins, so you could broadcast updates via email/IRC/XMPP etc. There is also the Radiator Plugin if you want to have a dashboard screen visible to all.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! There is no reason is has to be Twitter (or similar). I was thinking that I liked the way [cyanogen mod status](http://twitter.com/cmsrc) does the updates for their build and was thinking of having a per check in status update and a build status update.

Answer (score 2):

For a friendly dashboard for a project, I prefer using **[Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/)**, called from the maven script run by the Jenkin job.
Regarding ClearCase, I monitor [issue 8305](http://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-8305), for the Jenkin ClearCase plugin to be able to get the right config spec out of a file, instead of copy-paste it in the job directly.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you're asking for, but you can always retrieve the hudson status xml over it's web API.

Here's a simple adobe Flex view of the data:

[Hudson -CI Screen saver setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912261/hudson-ci-screen-saver-setup/3912329#3912329)

Of course the Hudson Radiator View Plugin, and the [Extreme Feedback plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/eXtreme+Feedback+Panel+Plugin) are good for this purpose too.